# Show div if variable changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Currently I have script which displays the name of the users current connected profile (result.profile) . If the profile is changed it successfully displays the new profile.

What I am looking to do, is show a div (#profileupdate) which clearly alerts the user that a profile (result.profile) has changed.

I was thinking this may be achieved with onchange function or addEventListener but I’m struggling to get it working.

This part currently works:

```
<script>
case “profile”:
    $("#sub-profile”).show();
    if(result.active) $("#btn-disconnect").show();
    new_profile=result.profile;
    html+="<tr><td><label for=‘profile-auto'>Auto select profile</label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name=‘profile-auto' id=‘profile-auto' "+ (result.auto?"checked”:””)’><label class='msg2' id='msg-auto-profile’></label></td></tr>";
    if(!result.disabled){
    html+="<tr><td>Current Profile</td><td>"+ result.profile+"</td></tr>";
    }
</script>
```

But I’ve not yet been able to display div when result.profile changes:

```
<script>
document.getElementById(“result-profile“).addEventListener("change", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById(“result-profile“);
    $(“#profileupdate”).show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is with the fancy quotes? Does your real code have them? If yes, that is your problem. And change events are for inputs. So do you have an input with `id="result-profile"`? If the variable changes, than you need to do something else to monitor the varaible and detect when the value chanegs.

Comment: Where does your `result` variable come from? Do you get if by any ajax functions? If yes, why don't you show the div in the success handler of the ajax function?